Find the number of ways to choose a $\{b_i\}_{{i=1}}^{k+1}$ from the first $n$ positive integers such that $b_{i+1}-b_i\ge a_i$ for $1\le i\le k-1$
This is problem 9.81 from A path to combinatorics for undergraduates.
Let $k$ and $n$ be positive integers, and let $a_1,a_2,...,a_k$ be positive integers. Determine the number of ways to choose a $(k+1)$-term sequence $\{b_i\}_{{i=1}}^{k+1}$ from the first $n$ positive integers such that $b_{i+1}-b_i\ge a_i$ for $1\le i\le k-1$.
Here is my attempt
Note that for any sequence $\{b_i\}_{{i=1}}^{k+1}$ satisfying the given conditions, we have
$$n\ge b_k\ge a_{k-1}+b_{k-1}\ge a_{k-1}+a_{k-2}+b_{k-2}\ge ...\ge \sum_{i=1}^{k-1}a_i+b_1\ge \sum_{i=1}^{k-1}a_i+1$$
So if $n\lt \sum_{i=1}^{k-1}a_i+1$, then the number of ways is $0$.
I don't know how to proceed for the case $n\gt \sum_{i=1}^{k-1}a_i+1$.
Any help is appreciated. Thank you.
Edit: I'm going to assume the author meant $b_{i+1}-b_i\ge a_i$ for $1\le i\le k$ rather than just for $1\le i\le k-1$, since I don't think there would be a reason to define $a_k$ otherwise.

Hint:  consider the gaps between the $b_i$, including the initial and final gaps.  We know that the "interior" gaps  must satisfy the given inequality.  Adjust the gaps accordingly to make this into a traditional Stars and Bars problem

Given any sequence $\{b_i\}_{{i=1}}^{k+1}$ satisifying the conditions in the question, define $y_1=b_1-1$, $y_{i+1}=b_{i+1}-b_i$ for any $1\le i\le k,$ and $y_{k+2}=n-b_{k+1}$.
We have $\sum_{i=1}^{k+2}y_i=(b_1-1)+(\sum_{i=1}^{k}b_{i+1}-b_i)+(n-b_{k+1})=n-1$
Note that $y_{i+1}\ge a_i$ for any $1\le i\le k$.
Now define $z_1=y_1$, $z_{i+1}=y_{i+1}-a_i$ for any $1\le i\le k$ and $z_{k+2}=y_{k+2}$.
We have $\sum_{i=1}^{k+2}z_i=(y_1)+(\sum_{i=1}^{k}y_{i+1}-a_i)+(y_{k+2})=(\sum_{i=1}^{k+2}y_i)-(\sum_{i=1}^{k}a_i)=n-1-\sum_{i=1}^{k}a_i$
Note that $z_i\ge 0$ for any $1\le i\le k+2$. By Stars and Bars, there are $\binom{n-1-\sum_{i=1}^{k}a_i+k+1}{k+1}$ such sequences $\{z_i\}_{i=1}^{k+2}$. By bijection principle, it follows that there are $\binom{n-1-\sum_{i=1}^{k}a_i+k+1}{k+1}$ sequences $\{b_i\}_{{i=1}}^{k+1}$ satisifying the conditions in the question.
